# how many strings are length 10 with 5 1's and 5 0's are there?

Tags: combinatorics

I used generating functions and got $A(x,y)=(x+y)^{10}$. Then I found the coefficient of the $x^5y^5$ and got $252$. Is that the correct answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct. Its $\binom{10}{5} = 252$

Comment: @Ganymede  is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The easier way is to consider $10$-slot string with each slot you put either a $0$ or a $1$. Then you count the number of ways to distribute the $5$ $1$'s which is $252$, and the rest for the $0$'s

Comment: @Ganymede i see thank you

Comment: The middle number in the $10$th row (counting from $0$) in Pascal triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

In the sequence of $10$ characters, you have to choose which five are 1s. The other five are then forced to be zeros. So the number of ways is
$10 \choose 5$, which is $252$.